# Name used in the static data member definition after unqualified id

Tags: c++, class, static

From the sec. 3.4.1/13 of N3797:

> A name used in the definition of a static data member of class X
>   (9.4.2) (after the qualified-id of the static member) is looked up as
>   if the name was used in a member function of X.

it is unclear how is looked up a name used in the definition of a static data member of class X after the **unqualified-id** of the data member. I need a quote from the standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All is writed in 9.4.2. Quote from n3376 9.4.2/2

> In the definition at namespace scope, the name of the static data
>   member shall be qualified by its class name using the :: operator. **The
>   initializer expression in the definition of a static data member is in
>   the scope of its class** [ Example:
>
> ```
> class process 
> { 
>    static process* run_chain; 
>    static process* running; 
> };
>
> process* process::running = get_main();
> process* process::run_chain = running;
> ```
>
> The static data member run_chain of class process is defined in global
>   scope; the notation process ::run_chain specifies that the member
>   run_chain is a member of class process and in the scope of class
>   process. **In the static data member definition, the initializer
>   expression refers to the static data member running of class process.**
>   — end example ]

Comment: Many thanks for your quote. But can you clarify the following: Why does in-class definition of static non-const members forbid? Give me a reference to a corresponding clause.